# Почему неправильно считает

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
double x, s, a, b;
int main() { 
  cout<<"vvedite 2 storoni treugolnika i ugol megdu nimi\n";
  cin >> a >> b >>x;
    s = 1.0/2*a*b*sin(x);
  cout<<"Ploshad rovna"<<"  "<< s ;
  getch(); 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Скорее всего, угол в градусах вводите, а не в радианах.

Answer (score 1):

Вместо `sin(x)` напишите `sin(3.14159265359*x/180)`.